# how to close a piped process when the receiver terminates

Tags: c#, windows, netcat

I'm on Windows 8 using C# with .NET 4.5.

I am using ncat to listen for a UDP broadcast and pipe it into the stdin of another process.

```
ncat -lu -5555 | MyProcess.exe
```

Upon receiving a line matching a certain pattern, MyProcess.exe spawns some processes and dies.

The problem is that ncat is still alive, and sending its output apparently to nowhere.

I am driving this command from a batch script.

What is the best way to stop ncat when MyProcess.exe dies?

Comment: Off-topic vote why? A question about best practices for managing processes in C# seems on-topic to me.

Comment: Certainly on-topic.  Probably someone just saw a command line and didn't read the rest of the question carefully enough.  But I don't think there's any way to do this.  Instead, consider running `ncat` from within MyProcess.exe - that way, your code can terminate it when it is no longer needed.